# Puppet, managing two depending file resources?

Tags: puppet

I cannot figure out, how to deal with case when I have 2 resources managed by puppet, depending on each other (one is parent of another), and both are set to be `absent`. Test case below. Directories doesn't exists already, but puppet complains about creating files there. How to fix this manifest?

```
$ find . -type f
./modules/test/manifests/init.pp
./modules/test/files/b/x
./modules/test/files/b/z
./modules/test/files/b/y
./manifests/site.pp
./test.pp
$ cat manifests/site.pp 
## site.pp

node default {
    include test
}
$ cat modules/test/manifests/init.pp 
## init.pp

class test {
    file { 'dir1':
        ensure  => absent,
        path    => '/tmp/a',
        before  => File['dir2'],
    }

    file { 'dir2':
        ensure  => absent,
        path    => '/tmp/a/b',
        source  => 'puppet:///modules/test/b',
        force   => true,
        purge   => true,
        recurse => true,

    }
}
$ puppet apply --modulepath ./modules manifests/site.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for localhost in environment production in 0.11 seconds
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/z20140523-14751-1qpqnds-9'
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/z20140523-14751-1qpqnds-9'
Wrapped exception:
cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/z20140523-14751-1qpqnds-9'
Error: /Stage[main]/Test/File[/tmp/a/b/z]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/z20140523-14751-1qpqnds-9'
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/y20140523-14751-1bxpkko-9'
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/y20140523-14751-1bxpkko-9'
Wrapped exception:
cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/y20140523-14751-1bxpkko-9'
Error: /Stage[main]/Test/File[/tmp/a/b/y]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/y20140523-14751-1bxpkko-9'
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/x20140523-14751-1u3y3dl-9'
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/x20140523-14751-1u3y3dl-9'
Wrapped exception:
cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/x20140523-14751-1u3y3dl-9'
Error: /Stage[main]/Test/File[/tmp/a/b/x]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: cannot generate tempfile `/tmp/a/b/x20140523-14751-1u3y3dl-9'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.14 seconds
```

EDIT:

Full context:

```
## init.pp

class test {

    $is_master  = false

    if $is_master {
        $file_ensure        = present
        $directory_ensure   = directory
    } else {
        $file_ensure        = absent
        $directory_ensure   = absent
    }

    file { 'dir1':
        ensure  => $directory_ensure,
        path    => '/tmp/a',
        before  => File['dir2'],
    }

    file { 'dir2':
        ensure  => $directory_ensure,
        path    => '/tmp/a/b',
        source  => 'puppet:///modules/test/b',
        force   => true,
        purge   => true,
        recurse => true,
    }
}
```

You cannot remove dir1, because it'll fail on master, I need to make it works on master and slave.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `File['dir2']` resource completely, and change `File['dir1']` to:

```
file { 'dir1':
    ensure  => absent,
    path    => '/tmp/a',
    recurse => true,
    force   => true,
}
```

With your code, you're trying to remove `/tmp/a`, before you remove `/tmp/a/b`. If you remove `/tmp/a` first, then `/tmp/a/b` can't even exist. You want the reverse order.

However, that is not even necessary. If you're removing `/tmp/a`, there's no reason to create a resource definition to remove anything inside it.

Comment: It's not so simple, because it's only a small piece of whole code. It have to be two separate resources.

Comment: @fazie Then perhaps you should tell us exactly what you're doing so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my question, and added more background.